# Why breakpoint is not reached in VisualStudio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> li = new List<int>() { 1, 20, 30, 4, 5 };
        GetNosLessThan5(li);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> GetNosLessThan5(List<int> numbers)
    {
        foreach (var v in numbers)
        {
            if (v < 5)
                yield return v;
        }
    }
```

I have put a debug point at the start of void main. When I press f11 continuously, the yellow arrow covers only the main function block and the debugging terminates. it never reaches the "getnoslessthan5" function at all.Confused.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're never actually iterating over the result, thus the actual body of the `GetNosLessThan5` function is never executed. The compiler creates an iterator under the hood, but something needs to actually enumerate it for the function body to run.

See the [MSDN Documentation about Iterators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx).

> An iterator can be used to step through collections such as lists and arrays.
>
> An iterator method or get accessor performs a custom iteration over a collection. An iterator method uses the Yield (Visual Basic) or yield return (C#) statement to return each element one at a time. When a Yield or yield return statement is reached, the current location in code is remembered. Execution is restarted from that location the next time the iterator function is called.
>
> You consume an iterator from client code by using a For Each…Next (Visual Basic) or foreach (C#) statement or by using a LINQ query.

Comment: But sir inside main there is a call to the function right? so the function should be executed right. ?

Comment: @callyaser No, you're calling a function that returns an `IEnumerable` - in other words, `GetNosLessThan5` returns an object that says "I can be iterated over". It does **not** return the result of the enumeration - for that you'd have to call `.ToList` or a similar method that actually calculates the numbers. `Iterators` are a bit of compiler magic in C#.

Comment: (This is an optimization technique since Iterators can be expensive to run, or even infinite. It's the callers responsibility to decide if, when, and how long to run it)